# Is there a way to make the iOS default keyboard show the numbers version first?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have an input field which for most purposes the data is numbers only, but does allow for alpha input. I want to use the default iOS keyboard, but I want its state to initially show the version with the numbers and then, if needed, toggle to the alpha keys. Is this possible?

[image: Numbers Version]

Comment: Have you looked at the `keyboardType` property?

Comment: And this is probably why I didn't find this, that was so simple... Thanks!